# how to extract a block that is in the middle of a text in a file

Tags: python-2.7

how to extract a block that is in the middle of a text.

Example:

```
User authority


--------------


              Subscriber number  =  189159


             Call-out authority  =  Intra-office


                                 =  Local


                                 =  Local toll


                                 =  National toll


                                 =  International toll


                                 =  Intra-Centrex


                                 =  Outgoing Centrex


                                 =  Intra-office national toll


                                 =  Intra-office international toll


                                 =  Intra-centrex local toll


                                 =  Intra-centrex national toll


                                 =  Intra-centrex international toll


                                 =  Intra-office local toll


                                 =  Customize call-out authority 1


                                 =  Customize call-out authority 2


                                 =  Customize call-out authority 3


                                 =  Customize call-out authority 4


                                 =  Customize call-out authority 7


                                 =  Customize call-out authority 9


                                 =  Customize call-out authority 10


                                 =  Customize call-out authority 11


                                 =  Customize call-out authority 12


                                 =  Customize call-out authority 13


                                 =  Customize call-out authority 14


                                 =  Customize call-out authority 15


                                 =  Customize call-out authority 16


              Call-in authority  =  Intra-office


                                 =  Local


                                 =  Local toll


                                 =  National toll


                                 =  International toll


                                 =  Intra-Centrex


                                 =  Incoming Centrex


                                 =  Intra-office national toll


                                 =  Intra-office international toll


                                 =  Intra-centrex local toll


                                 =  Intra-centrex national toll


                                 =  Intra-centrex international toll


                                 =  Intra-office local toll


                                 =  Customize call-in authority 1


                                 =  Customize call-in authority 2


                                 =  Customize call-in authority 3


                                 =  Customize call-in authority 4


                                 =  Customize call-in authority 5


                                 =  Customize call-in authority 6


                                 =  Customize call-in authority 7


                                 =  Customize call-in authority 8


                                 =  Customize call-in authority 9


                                 =  Customize call-in authority 10


                                 =  Customize call-in authority 11


                                 =  Customize call-in authority 12


                                 =  Customize call-in authority 13


                                 =  Customize call-in authority 14


                                 =  Customize call-in authority 15


                                 =  Customize call-in authority 16


      Call-in Barring Authority  =  NULL


                        K value  =  K0
```

I just want to extract the block that begins with              **Call-out authority  =  Intra-office** until       **Call-in Barring Authority  =  NULL**

This is my code:

```
begin='             Call-out authority  ='
end='      Call-in Barring Authority  ='

with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    t = f.read()
    i = t.find(begin)
    j=t.startswith(end)
    print(t[i:j])
```

data.txt is file.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `j=t.find(end)` instead of `j=t.startswith(end)` ? Startswith doesn't work in this example, because `end` string probably starts with more spaces, than you typed. You could match better with regular expressions (look at `import re`), but `find` seems to do its jobs here.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply read line by line until you find `begin` and then until you find `end`:

```
begin='             Call-out authority  ='
end='      Call-in Barring Authority  ='

with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    for t in f:
        if t.startswith(beg): break
    print t
    for t in f:
        if t.starstwith(end): break
        print t,
```